# How to detect columns of rectangles in mask image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have found contours of some rectangles in an image and created a mask as shown below. What I am trying to do is finding those two columns of rectangles as highlighted in the image.

The source image:

[image: Source image]

Columns highlighted:

[image: Highlighted]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: In the source image, you highlighted that drawing rectangle or you found that by coding ?

Comment: No I didn't find the red rectangles. I just highlighted them with Photoshop for posting here.

Comment: You can play with the `dilation` function of opencv which may combine those small rectangle's contours. Also it 'd be better if you share source image without drawing so people who wanna help can play on it

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I just updated the source image. I was thinking about using HoughLinesP. But it doesn't give appropriate results since there may be some smaller similar columns of rectangles in the middle of image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if one can achieve that with simple algorithm. If those inline-vertical rectangle does not change their position, You could just define (hardcoded) ROI (region of interest) for them, based on pixel coordinates.

If not using any machine learning to solve this, defining ROI is Your best option.

Feel free to ask, if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the position of rectangles change in different images. What machine learning path do you recommend?

Comment: This is not a solution to this question, drawing is not a way, we talking about DETECTION

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk no one mentioned drawing. I wondered if images are static, then defining ROI for extraction would be the easies and quick-processing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the desired columns have significantly more contours than the other columns – as shown in the given example image – simple dilation with some vertical structuring element might be sufficient to find those columns:

1. Load image as grayscale, get rid of JPG artifacts.
2. Dilation with "small" vertical structuring element to combine all contours within a column.
3. Opening with "large" vertical structuring element to neglect all smaller contours. The two columns in question will now have quite large contours.
4. For safety reasons: Again, dilation with "small" vertical structuring element. Since the columns are slightly rotated, skewed, ... single pixels might've been falsely removed by the opening.
5. Find remaining contours.
6. For each contour: Get the bounding boxes in two steps, since we have to refine the bounding box by using the original image (because of step 4).

That'd be the full Python code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image, get rid of JPG artifacts
img = cv2.imread('gXylF.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Dilating using vertical structuring element to combine contours
mask = cv2.dilate(img, kernel=np.ones((21, 1)))

# Opening using vertical structuring element to neglect small contours
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel=np.ones((201, 1)))

# Dilating using rectangular structuring element; for safety reasons:
# Single pixels might've been falsely removed by the opening
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel=np.ones((11, 11)))

# Find remaining contours w.r.t. the OpenCV version
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Iterate remaining contours
for i, cnt in enumerate(cnts):

    # Get bounding rectangle of contour, and region of interest (ROI)
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Get bounding rectangle of actual values in ROI; the contour of the
    # mask is larger than the actual contours in the original image
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(roi)
    roi = roi[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imwrite('{}.png'.format(i), roi)
```

The two exported images look like this:

[image: Column 1] [image: Column 2]

If you, instead, wanted to mark the regions of interest (ROIs) within the original image, pay attention to use the correct coordinates of the bounding boxes (refined coordinates are w.r.t. to the first cut ROI).

If your other images show more rotation, skew, ... you'd might need to re-draw the contours w.r.t. the original image, if neighbouring, small contours should be neglected completely.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```